# QML converting string of datetime to a qml parsable date failing on GMT time zone

Tags: qt, date, parsing, timezone, qml

In a QML (javascript) function, I am trying to parse a date from the backend. All is working except that the date contains the `GMT+0100`. This causes the conversion to invalidate. For instance:

```
var dateTimeString = "Thu Sep 12 10:56:06 2019"
console.log("testing date conversion: ", Date.fromLocaleString(locale, dateTimeString, "ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy"))
```

Works totally fine and returns

```
testing date converstion: Thu Sep 12 10:56:06 2019 GMT+0100
```

However the date actually comes through as a string like

```
var dateTimeString = "Thu Sep 12 10:56:06 2019 GMT+0100"
```

And this causes it to be invalid when it tries to convert. I realise I could strip off the `GMT+0100` however this may contain useful information. 
What is the correct way to get it to respect the time zone? I tried adding a `t` at the end, however this doesn't fix it. (I understand `t` is the timezone).

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this link [Development for Sailfish OS: Features of working with dates and time zones](https://weekly-geekly.github.io/articles/324812/index.html) is useful...

Answer (score 0):

you could use the javascript "Date" to parse the string before converting it with Qt.

It would then look something like this:

```
var dateTimeString = "Thu Sep 12 10:56:06 2019 GMT+0100"
var dateTime = new Date(dateTimeString)
console.log("testing date conversion: ", Qt.formatDateTime(new Date(dateTime), "ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy"))
```